# Gutenberg Custom Block Getting All Posts

Tags: rest-api, block-editor, wp-api

I'm trying to create a custom block but I need some assistance.

I'm attempting to setup a `<select>` in the editor that lists all the posts. I'm not very experienced at the api yet but after reading the docs, it seems that the below line should work to get the posts.

```
wp.api.collections.Posts().fetch()
```

The problem is, however, I'm getting a nice error of:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'collections' of undefined

How can I get a list of all the posts for selection within the editor, or is it just outside the realm of possibility?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to loading the `wp-api` script as mentioned [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/backbone-javascript-client/#using):

```php
wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-api' ); // or use below when enqueueing as dependency
//wp_enqueue_script( 'my_script', 'path/to/my/script', array( 'wp-api' ) );
```

You should also know that each collection is a function (equivalent to a class in PHP), so you need to use the `new` keyword to instantiate a collection. [Example](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/backbone-javascript-client/#collection-examples):

```js
var postsCollection = new wp.api.collections.Posts();
postsCollection.fetch( {
    data: { per_page: 2 }
} ).done( function( posts ){
    console.log( 'Title of the first item is: ' + posts[0].title.rendered );
} );
```

However, with Gutenberg, you'd likely want to or you can use the `api-fetch`/`wp.apiFetch` [package](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/master/packages/api-fetch):

1. Enqueue the `wp-api-fetch` script:

   ```php
   wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-api-fetch' ); // or use below when enqueueing as dependency
   //wp_enqueue_script( 'my_script', 'path/to/my/script', array( 'wp-api-fetch' ) );
   ```
2. And just call `wp.apiFetch()` like so:

   ```js
   wp.apiFetch( { path: '/wp/v2/posts?per_page=2' } ).then( function( posts ){
       console.log( 'Title of the first item is: ' + posts[0].title.rendered );
   } );
   ```

   `path` is a REST API route like [`/wp/v2/posts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#list-posts) which can optionally be appended with one or more arguments for that specific route.

> How can I get a list of all the posts for selection within the editor

If you're on the admin screen for editing or creating a post, then the `wp-api-fetch` script has already been enqueued *if* the block editor is enabled for that post. And if you're specifically creating a block, then you can actually use [`getEntityRecords()`](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/master/packages/core-data#getEntityRecords) along with [`withSelect`](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/master/packages/data#withSelect) (for listening to state changes). See the [Latest Posts block](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/packages/block-library/src/latest-posts/edit.js) for sample implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enqueue WP API javascript, You should have added the above code in one of your custom files, suppose your file name is myscript.js

And you should have enqueued it somewhere, modify that and attach wp-api as a dependency like this :

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'my_script', 'path/to/my/myscript.js', array( 'wp-api' ) );
```

Comment: Added `wp-api` as a dependency, thanks. Now I'm getting new errors on the same line though `TypeError: this._reset is not a function`. Any ideas?